# Why does python's datetime.isocalendar() and datetime.year differ?

Tags: python, datetime

Try the following in python 2.6:

```
newyear_2012 = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(1325419200)
newyear.year # returns 2012
newyear.isocalendar() # return (2011, 52, 7)
```

What's the deal here?  Is this a bug?  I couldn't find it documented, but maybe I didn't look in the right place.

If I convert that unix timestamp [here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm), it tells me: Sun, 01 Jan 2012 12:00:00 GMT

**Update:**
The answers below explain how this is not a python error but rather due to the ISO specification.  If you want to get the week number that won't ever put the first few days of the year in week #52, you can try the following:

```
week_no = int(time.strftime("%U", datetime_object.timetuple()))
```

I'm not sure what standard that's corresponds to, but it behaves more intuitively from my perspective (in my application week numbers within a year should be ascending with time).

Comment: The behavior of `datetime.date.isocalendar()` is not determined by your intuition, but by ISO 8601.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/calendar/isocalendar_text2.htm

*the first week of the ISO calendar year is the earliest week that contains at least four days of the month of January...(assumed to start on Monday)*

That makes ISO 2012 begin on **Jan 2**.  Your timestamp is **Sun, 01 Jan 2012 12:00:00 GMT**

Answer (score 2):

See the diagram [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).  Jan 1 2012 is in week 52 of 2011.